# Не могу подключить JS к Index.html

Tags: javascript

Прохожу скаченные курсы. Есть задание на основе которого построил код. Задание в 2х словах нужно из массива объектов создать select в index.html.
select получилось сделать по коду ниже.

```
let selectMassive1 = [
  {value: 'Чебуратор', label: 'Чебурашка-какашка'},
  {value: 'Генадий', label: 'Генератор'},
  {value: 'Шапокляп', label: 'Шапка'},
  {value: 'ГариПотный', label: 'Потноглаз'},
];

function createSelect1(selectMassive, value) {   //функция с 2мя аргуменетами название массива и значение селекта по умолчанию
  const body = document.body;                //ссылка какая то на документ
  let select = document.createElement('select');   //создадим селект тег в переменную
  body.append(select);              //переместим селек в боди
  
  for (let selectM of selectMassive) {
    let option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = selectM.value;
    option.innerHTML = selectM.label;
    select.append(option);
    if (option.value === value) {
      option.setAttribute('selected', true);
    } 
  }
  return select
}

let m = console.log(createSelect1(selectMassive1, 'ГариПотный'));
console.log(m);
```

В логе все работает. Переношу сам код в HTML все работает. Начинаю подключать по заданию код (не совсем тут понимаю), получаю ошибку в консоле и ничего не выводится. Вот HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="/home-task/6/js/main.js"></script>
    <title>Задание 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Селект в самой странице:</h2>
    <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Пункт 1</option>
        <option value="">Пункт 2</option>
    </select>
    <h2>Через скрипт выводим селект:</h2>
<script id="select"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Вот задание по переносу:

Создайте базовую html-разметку в файле index.html. В неё поместите получившийся код с помощью `<script src="./main.js"></script>`. Внутри другого тэга script перед `</body>` поместите код, который создаст новый select с произвольным массивом значений и поместит его в любое место в body.

Путь прописал верный. Ошибка значит вот такая в консоле браузере:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of null
    at createSelect1 (main.js:11)
    at main.js:25
createSelect1 @ main.js:11
(anonymous) @ main.js:25
```

Comment: Подключено успешно. Проблема тут в том, что код выполняется **до** создания элементов страницы.

Comment: Подключайте скрипт перед закрывающим тегом `<body>`

Comment: Спасибо я понял, что неправильно сделал. я думал нужно в хед подключить туда же где стили.  (а про head вообще ни слова в задании). Все заработало.

Comment: Подключайте скрипт перед закрывающим тегом - может всё же использовать современные возможности браузеров? https://learn.javascript.ru/script-async-defer

Comment: @Андрей: можно подключать и в `<head>`, но тогда все обращения к элементам и их свойствам должны происходить [после загрузки DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded#domcontentloaded).